# Explanation about difference in original and bootstrap value

Tags: r, resampling, statistics-bootstrap

I have the following function; (1) to calculate the deviance difference for each variable I have and (2) to do bootstrap for the deviance difference that I calculated in the first step

```
set.seed(1001)

xfunction <- function(d,i)
{
glm.snp1 <- glm(PHENOTYPE~d[i], family="binomial", data=training1)
null <- glm.snp1$null.deviance
residual <- glm.snp1$deviance
dDeviance <- null-residual
return(dDeviance)
}

myboot <- function(d)
{
boot(d,xfunction, R=1000)
}

result <- lapply(training1,function(x)myboot(x))
```

So basically from the result I got the values for original dDeviance (without bootstrap) and I can calculate the mean(dDeviance) from the bootstrap. I need help in explaining why the original and the mean bootstrap values are too different? For example for one of the variable, the original value of dDeviance is 0.024 while the bootstrap mean of dDeviance is 0.000412.

Comment: That seems unlikely, as the distribution of bootstrapped statistics is mostly around the statistic in the original data. Looking at your code, I think your issue lies in the indexing. You do use d[i], but still use the original training set and the original phenotype.

Comment: Thanks @Heroka for the comment. I agree with you too that the value should be around the original value. I tried to get rid of data in the xfunction, but it can't identify where is my PHENOTYPE coming from. I appreciate if you could suggest amendments in my function. For your information my outcome is PHENOTYPE and predictors consist of 1500 of SNPs with 1000 samples.

Comment: In my experience with bootstrapping, I had a function with took a dataset containing everything I needed and indices, and then used that. So Phenotype should be in training1, you can then fit your model with `data=d[i,]`.

Comment: I agree with @Heroka, you should subset the data.frame during bootstrapping and not in the formula. I also don't understand what you do there with your `lapply` loop.

Comment: Thank you both for the comments. I will try to work on that. Well the idea I put lapply there so that it will calculate the dDeviance for each of the column in training1[,2:1501] and bootstrap the value using boot function.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, it's is better to subset the data.frame indices, to make it compatible with `boot`. If you want to iterate through different variables, and apply this function, it's better to do it within the iterate.

For every bootstrap, you fit the different models and extract the values.

So we re-write the function, and it takes in an extra formula parameter, `indep_var` which specifies the columns to regress PHENOTYPE against:

```
xfunction <- function(d,ind,indep_var){

    dDeviance = sapply(indep_var,function(V){
         f = reformulate(V,response="PHENOTYPE")  
         glm.snp1 <- glm(f, family="binomial", data=d[ind,])
         glm.snp1$null.deviance-glm.snp1$deviance
    })
return(dDeviance)
}
```

We can set up an example dataset:

```
set.seed(111)
training1 = data.frame(PHENOTYPE=rbinom(100,1,0.5),matrix(rnorm(500),ncol=5))

head(training1)
  PHENOTYPE         X1          X2         X3         X4         X5
1         1  0.1916634 -0.09152026 -0.9685094 -1.0503824 -0.9137690
2         1  1.5525443 -1.87430581  0.9119331  0.3251424  0.1126909
3         0  0.9142423 -0.66416202  0.0928326 -2.1048716 -2.3597249
4         1  0.3586254  0.20341282 -0.5329309 -0.9551027 -1.5693983
5         0  0.1750956 -2.59444339 -1.6669055 -0.5306399  1.2274569
6         0 -0.8472678 -0.09373393 -0.5743455  0.8274405  0.7620480
```

And try this on data:

```
xfunction(training1,1:nrow(training1),indep_var=c("X1","X2","X3"))
       X1        X2        X3 
0.1189847 0.2512539 0.2684927
```

Then using bootstrap:

```
library(boot)
boot(training1,xfunction,R=1000,indep_var=c("X1","X2","X3"))

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = training1, statistic = xfunction, R = 1000, indep_var = c("X1", 
    "X2", "X3"))


Bootstrap Statistics :
     original   bias    std. error
t1* 0.1189847 1.033286    1.564971
t2* 0.2512539 1.047503    1.863012
t3* 0.2684927 1.005062    1.747959
```